# Vue JS - Make a function like browser's ctrl + f (with scrolling)

Tags: vue.js

I have a site where users can send messages to each other and its done with an overlay with vue-js. My question is there a function that is like ctrl + f that finds a specific string, highlights it, and then scrolls to it if its off-screen?

Currently I am using find() but it doesn't scroll to the string if its offscreen, any help?

Comment: You could try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto

Comment: Show your code you're using to scroll.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy im currently using window.find(word)